# How to change events background colour of a type in fullCalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, fullcalendar

I want change colour of all events with a parameter = 0 on my database when I load all this to my fullCalendar added in my php file. But I can't determine this because I load all with this functions:

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events:  JSON.parse(json_events),
    utc: true,
  header: {
        left: 'prev,next today',
        center: 'title',
        right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
    },
  editable: true,
  droppable: true, 
  ...
```

I don't know how to access json_events into line events:  JSON.parse(json_events), to change parameter colour...

How can I change background color?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can try this .

```
{
  title: 'Teste1',
  start: new Date(y, m, d, 10, 30),
  allDay: false,
  editable: false,
  backgroundColor: '#SomeColor'
},
{
  title: 'Teste2',
  start: new Date(y, m, d, 11, 40),
  allDay: false,
  backgroundColor: '#SomeOtherColor'
}
```